# OpenERP 7 with modules from OpenERP 6.1

Tags: python, odoo, erp

I have couple OpenERP modules implemented for **OpenERP 6.1** version. When I installed **OpenERP 7.0**, i copied these modules into addons folder for OpenERP 7. After that, I tried to update modules list trough web interface, but nothings changed. Also, I started server again with options *--database=mydb --update=all*, but modules list didn't change. Did I miss something? Is it possible in OpenERP version 7, usage of modules from version 6.1?

Thanks for advice.

UPDATE:

I already exported my database from version 6.1 in *.sql file. Will it OpenERP 7 work, if I just import these data in new database, which I created with OpenERP 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Openerp 6.1 modules directly can not be used in openerp  7. You have to do some basic changes 
in openerp 6.1 modules. Like tree, form tag compulsory string and verision="7" include in form. If you have inherited some basic modules like  sale, purchase then you have to do changes in inherit xpath etc. Some objects res.parter.address removed then you have take care of this and replace with res.partner.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you point me on some link with documentation related to development changes in 7.0?

Comment: You can get new development information from (http://v6.openerp.com/node/1272) release notes of openerp 7

Comment: I know for that documentation, but it's not useful for me. Mostly, this release notes are based on changes in user interface. I need documentation from programming aspect. For example, what changes were made in model data, creating xml views, inheritance etc. After some googling, I didn't find anything useful, except some forum threads. If you know some useful links, please share with me. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately!!! There is not such kind of documentation :( Openerp documentations very bad :(

Comment: So it is very easy porting modules from 6.1 to 7.0. Then why are there so many 6 community modules unported to 7 two years later?